# how to see full 'ldd' path details, instead of "file not found"?

Tags: ldd

When running ldd command when the path doesnt exist I'm getting 'file not found' instead of path.
bash-3.2$ ldd curl
        libcurl.so.4 =>  /usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4
        libldap.so.5 =>  /usr/lib/libldap.so.5
        librt.so.1 =>    /lib/librt.so.1
        libssl.so.1.0.0 =>       (file not found)
        libcrypto.so.1.0.0 =>    (file not found)

Is there an option to see which file not found? the full path?

Answer (score 3):

ldd is searching in the library search paths mentioned in /etc/ld.so.conf. Or it might use the environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH. As far as I can see, it looks at least in /usr/local/lib, /usr/lib and /lib which is the default on most systems. It fails to find libssl.so.1.0.0 in these three locations. That's why you get the 'file not found' message.

One reason might be you don't have libssl.so.1.0.0 installed. Maybe some other version.

Another reason might be it is installed somewhere else. The application which needs to load the shared library either has that path hardcoded or is using LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

anyways, to answer your question: the full path of libssl.so.1.0.0 cannot be found by ldd, thats why you get the error.

to find it, you have to manually search for it. one simple way would be

```
find / -ls | grep libssl.so
```

or better (if you only want your system disk to be searched)

```
find / -mount -ls | grep libssl.so
```

which might result in a lot of versions installed in several locations.

Comment: Once you've found a version in another location, you can add a symlink in the `/usr/local/lib` directory to that one external library (but be careful, I just needed to update my `/etc/ld.so.conf` which contained a reference to `usr/Local/lib` (watch the uppercase)).